# -fobjc-nonfragile-abi2 on LLVM compiler 2.0: unknow argument?

Tags: objective-c, ios, llvm-clang

I tried to built my project on Xcode with the LLVM compiler 2.0 and it gives this error:

```
error: unknown argument: '-fobjc-nonfragile-abi2'
```

I'm not familiar with the LLVM compilers, does anyone has a solution?

Removing the argument doesn't solve my problem, because my code has errors in that situation.

Comment: Isn't there an NDA on Xcode 4? At least I had to click something like this before they let me download it.

Comment: Don't know, but will remove the reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That option is no longer necessary as it is the default setting now in the latest version of LLVM.

Answer (score 1):

From clang man page:

> % man 1 clang ... Driver Options
>   -Xclang arg
>       Pass arg to the clang compiler. The -Xclang flag is a LLVM driver option for “Pass argument to the clang compiler,” and the the argument
>   here is -fobjc-nonfragile-abi2.

So, if you put them in reversed order, the compiler will use -fobjc-nonfragile-abi2 as cflag, which isn’t, and get you the error in return.

Looki Looki here:
http://digdog.tumblr.com/post/833744044